# jquery how to set radio button list item based on another radio button selection asp.net c#

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, radiobuttonlist

I have two radio button lists and would like to change the text of the list items in the second radio button list items based on a selection in the first radio button list.  Getting the selected value is working, but have not figured out how to set the individual text labels for the items in radio button 2. The code is below. Thanks very much.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=rb1.ClientID%>").change(function () {
                var rbvalue = $("input[@name=<%=rb1.ClientID%>]:radio:checked").val();
                if (rbvalue == "0") {
                <!-- need to: -->
                <!-- set rb2 list item 1 text to 'sample 1' -->
                <!-- set rb2 list item 2 text to 'sample 2' -->

                }
                else if (rbvalue == "1") {
                <!-- need to: -->
                <!-- set rb2 list item 1 text to 'sample 3' -->
                <!-- set rb2 list item 2 text to 'sample 4' -->
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here are the sample radio buttons in the code behind:

```
<asp:radiobuttonlist id="rb1" runat="server">
    <asp:listitem value="0">Option1</asp:listitem>
    <asp:listitem value="1">Option2</asp:listitem>
</asp:radiobuttonlist>
<asp:radiobuttonlist id="rb2" runat="server">
    <asp:listitem value="0" Text="change me 1"></asp:listitem>
    <asp:listitem value="1" Text="change me 2"></asp:listitem>
</asp:radiobuttonlist>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the radios specifically by using the syntax below

```
$("input[@name=<%=rb2.ClientID%>][value=0]")
$("input[@name=<%=rb2.ClientID%>][value=1]")
```

Just use `.text` to set the value

**Or**

```
$('[id*=rb2][value=0]').text('something')
$('[id*=rb2][value=1]').text('something else')
```

Comment: Tried that, and although it does change the text in the html <input> tag that is rendered, it does not change it in the <label for=> tag.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Since a label control is rendered you'll need to modify it instead of the actual radio button object. Right-clicking on it in Chrome or FF and choosing Inspect Element will show you the exact way it ends up being rendered to the browser.

```
$("#<%=rb2.ClientID%>").parent().find('label').text("your text here");
```

Comment: Inspecting the element in the browser and below is an example of what one radio button looks like.  The problem seems to be that it is rendered as 'label for' and not sure how to access that in jquery and change it:   <input id="_ctl0_ContentMain_rb2_0" type="radio" name="_ctl0:ContentMain:rb2_0" value="0" checked="checked"></input> <label for="_ctl0_ContentMain_rb2_0">change me 1</label>

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Below is the solution that works to change the text on the radio button list items:
$('[id*=rb2][value=0] + label').text('This works 0');
$('[id*=rb2][value=1] + label').text('This works 1');